# Можно ли убрать слэш в конце только у одной страницы в Django?

Tags: python, django

Хочу сделать динамическую генерацию sitemap на сайте (django) просто через обычную вьюху и html-шаблон.

```
class SitemapView(View):
    def get(self, request):

        context={
            #something
        }

        return render(request, 'shop/sitemap.html', context=context)
```

Запускаться это должно по адресу site.ru/sitemap.xml. Соответственно в urls.py пишу:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('sitemap.xml', SitemapView.as_view(), name='sitemap_view'),
]
```

Джанго добавляет в конце слэш, как и всем остальным страницам. Могу ли я как-то сделать исключение и не добавлять слэш в конце именно этому адресу?

Comment: В Django для этого есть отдельный фреймворк, смотрели? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/sitemaps/

Comment: спасибо, сейчас чекну

Answer (score 0):

Можно отключить автоматическое добавление слэшей:

```
APPEND_SLASH = False
```

[Подробнее...](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#append-slash)

Comment: Но тогда исчезнут редиректы везде, а я хочу только на одной странице :(